# Playing Wii Without a TV

Tags: nintendo-wii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a laptop as the monitor for a console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37227/using-a-laptop-as-the-monitor-for-a-console)

Is it possible to use the Wii without a TV? I don't have a TV, and have no plans to get one anytime soon.

I'm thinking something like a capture card or other specialized hardware might exist that would allow me to plug the Wii AV plugs (whatever they are) into my computer somehow.

...Not sure what exactly this would be like.

Comment: @agent86 that's specific to laptops and general beyond Wii. But sure.

Comment: The answers cover both the situations you're likely to run into - adding a capture card, or buying a compat. monitor.

Comment: Okay, fair enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a computer monitor you can definitely hook your Wii up to that. Have a look at [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/6799)